# Setting environment variable in gatling scala maven is not working from terminal

Tags: scala, maven, gatling

I am trying to read some of the values from environment variables for my gatling project. But when I execute maven command, environment values are not set. It is displaying null.

I tried

```xml
`mvn gatling:test -Dgatling.simulationClass=dev.RandomVinAndVehIdentifierGenerator -Dargline=env=dev.
```

I even created a bash file and then gave for a run but I am always getting below error.

No configuration setting found for key 'null'

I am reading the environment value using below code.

```
 val env = System.getenv("env")
  var url =  ConfigFactory.load().getString(env + ".hostURL")
```

env is always set null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't an **environment variables**, it's a **property**. You should use this:

```
System.getProperty("env")
```

for

```
mvn gatling:test -Denv=dev
```